# Paraphrase "the percentage of people"

Tags: paraphrasing

If the data is provided in percentage, can I say "the chart shows how many people (went to the cinema)" instead of the percentage of people going to the cinema? If I cannot, then is there any way to paraphrase it using a Wh-clause rather than other synonyms for percentage (such as proportion)?

Comment: Sure you can. Or *The chart shows **cinema audience numbers***, if you prefer.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to say that?  It's less clear, so why would you say it?

Comment: I just want to know more ways to paraphase than just using synonyms.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to give a very informal summary of what the chart is doing, it would be ok.

If you want to be precise, or describe it in a more academic/scientific sense, then it could be ambiguous or misleading.  "How many" would imply a total number could be determined from the chart.  A percentage without additional details does not describe "how many people" since you would need to know the applicable population to be able to figure out the number of people who went to the cinema from a chart showing the percentage.

Comment: You could say **the proportion of people** whilst still displaying percentages.

Comment: @PeterJennings OP specifically does not want to use the word "proportion"